# Is it possible and/or desirable to use a wireless mic through a guitar amp?

Tags: guitar, amplifiers

Was thinking of using a wired mic but wanted to explore wireless too.

It’s a crate brand amp with two quarter in inputs. Thanks!

Comment: What mic? Acoustic guitar? For what instrument?

Comment: Are you asking if you can use a wireless mic with the output from the mic coming out of the amp (ie plug in a guitar to one input and mic for vocals through the other input so both instrument and vox are amplified and heard through the amp)?  Or did you mean mic the cabinet so the audible output of the amp is sent to a mixer to be sent from there to a PA?

Answer (score 2):

It's quite possible! The mic, wired or wireless, will work with most amps, as mics (not powered ones though) should.

Guitar amps are balanced, tonally, to give the best sounds for *guitar*, which has a unique pitch range, so guitar amps cater for this. Vocals won't sound as good as they should, but that won't stop it working. And being wireless - with a good quality system - will not affect the quality of sound adversly.

The fact that, being a guitar amp, it has inputs that are 1/4" jack, may need an adaptor to get from XLR that is often associated with mics. If the mic is lo Z then it won't match the input impedance of the amp - which will be hi Z. It will still work, but there may be low volume problems - which a matching transformer can rectify. Also, a small speaker ( <12") will not really do justice to anyone's voice. But, you haven't said if it's for vox, acoustic guitar, or what?

Answer (score 1):

It is not desirable to use a wireless mic on-stage for a cabinet (it'd be a different story if it was handled, like a singer's mic).  Unless everything is wireless, the stage will be full of cables running every which way, including power for amps, pedalboards, DI-outs to the main board, etc.  The benefit of reducing clutter by one wire will not balance out your quality loss due to signal compression, and the unreliability brought on by another device running on a battery.

Answer (score -1):

Only in a crazy situation would I do that... If the out put of the pre amp.( Where the mic signal connects) is quarter you can. But a mic through a guitar amp is by nature no good. A mic that uses quarter rather than xlr 3 prong is usually low quality and unless in the expensive side wirless mic are notoriously unreliable. So I'm sorry to say unless just for fun it makes little sense... * Get a sure sm58 for 100 bucks a 3 prong cable and  an adapter.. sm58 do anything... You can even fry an egg.

Comment: “ You can even fry an egg.” we used to say you could use it as a hammer if needed. ;)

Comment: Did you mean 'input' not output? There are many mics out there that connect via 1/4" jacks that work fine. Just means they're high impedance, and work better in the appropriate inputs.